# CanCanCan redirect after rescue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, cancancan

In my `application.rb`, I have this:

```
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to authenticated_root_url, :alert => exception.message
  end
```

Which is fine.

What I want to do though, is once this rescue kicks in and sends them back to the login page, after they login, have them get redirected back to the page they were trying to access.

[This comment on this issue](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/811#issuecomment-15360194) has the following suggestion:

```
redirect_to exception.redirect_path, :alert => exception.message
```

But that doesn't work. I get this error:

```
undefined method `redirect_path' for #<CanCan::AccessDenied:0x007fca21c8eea0>
```

How do I achieve both? i.e. redirect to `authenticated_root_url` when they aren't logged in, and then `redirect :back` once they have successfully logged in?

Comment: You would stash the request url in the session when you catch the `CanCan::AccessDenied` and use that after you have signed the user in. There is a guide for how to do this with Devise authentication - same principle but slightly different. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update

Comment: Note that you need to redirect to the GET routes (new/edit) so doing this with a catch-all in your ApplicationController is kind of tricky - you may want to do this on per controller basis.

Answer (score 0):

Use **:back** in place of your path like so,

```
    rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
      redirect_to :back, :alert => exception.message
    end
```